# Doctrine Query to set temp column

Tags: sql, oracle, doctrine

My current table structure contains three columns, and I need to fetch those data with extra temporary column.

How to add temporary column at the end when I fetch?

Currently my code fetching the data is using doctrine. How to set parameter for temporary column?
I found `if (isset($flag))`, but flag is not a column name

```
  id   parentId    name
--------------------------------
  1       11        aa
  3       20        bb
================================
```

The structure I need when I fetch should be as below

```
id   parentId    name  flag  
--------------------------------
1       11        aa    1
3       20        bb    1
================================
```

My code is

```
public function getTitle($folderId) :array {
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('d');

$qb->select('d')
       ->where('d.id = :id')
       ->setParameter('id', $folderId);
}
```

Comment: So where does the value `1` for `flag` come from?

Comment: I thought to declare $flag=1 inside the  getTitle(),  and I don want to save this flag value to the database. When ever I try to fetch records, like title='%test%', I want to add extra temporary column saying true if found.

Comment: thanks for your reply, i have managed to set/reset flag in front end, much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you are trying to archieve but the "temporary column" can be a not persisted field, let's call it $flag as you said:

```
/** your class here */
private $flag;

// returns true if title matches the pattern, else return false
public function getFlag($pattern): bool
{
    return preg_match($pattern, $this->title);
}
```

On the other hand if you want to fetch records where title matches your '%test%' pattern you can do it in QueryBuilder

```
$qb->select('d')
   ->where('d.id = :id', $qb->expr()->like('d.title', $pattern))
   ->setParameter('id', $folderId)
   ->getQuery()
   ->getResult()
;
```